# How do I use sed properly to insert text into a file using a variable?

Tags: sed

How do I use sed properly to insert text into a file using a variable?

```
MYNIC_IP=`ip addr show eth0 | grep eth0 | awk '{ print $2; }' | sed 's/\/.*$//'`
```

Ok cool.

```
echo $MYNIC_IP
eth0: 172.31.43.190

sudo sed -i -e '1i'$MYNIC_IP /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
```

This results in part of the variable being added... just eth0:

Comment: Clarification, the variable ends up with a space. Not sure how to fix the delimiter so the whole variable gets added?

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote it so sed sees a single string including the space:

```
sed -i -e "1i\\
$MYNIC_IP"
```

With double quotes, you can still use variables inside and they will be expanded.

Comment: Tried that. Something to do with the : in the variable. Results in sed: -e expression #1, char 12: unknown command: `.'

Comment: @JBalrog: Try what I've written now.  You need a newline in the `i` command.

Comment: I have problems even understanding the question. Can one of you edit the  question so that it is clearer about what to achieve? Try to create a pair of Q/A which is useful for other users, too. Is the first half only showing how the variable gets filled and the actual question is how to prependt it to index.html?

Comment: @Yunnosch I believe I was clear. I stated a variable. This variable has an interesting issue, there is a : in the variable. As I stated echo $MYNIC_IP
eth0: 172.31.43.190   > when I use SED it drops out of the stream with an error. I realize it's an escape thats needed but I cannot seem to format one properly, hence asking for help. I need to use this odd shaped variable with SED.